# Local environment .htaccess php not redirecting

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Am creating a MVC framework and I have a public folder with the HTACCESS file. I want to be able to type for example "localhost/mvc/public/adjoasdjaos" and it should redirect me to the index.php page like "localhost/mvc/public/"

I have made several attempts which I commented out and it hasn't been working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    DirectoryIndex index.php

    # turn on rewriting
    RewriteEngine on
    
    # check that the request isn't actually a real file (e.g. an image)
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)?$ index.php?url=$1 [L]
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php [L]
    # redirect requests for BLAH to /edit.php?item=BLAH
    # RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/index.php?url=$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What happens exactly? The config you've posted would already seem to rewrite a request of the form `/mvc/public/adjoasdjaos` to `/mvc/public/index.php?url=adjoasdjaos`, providing `/mvc/public/adjoasdjaos.php` does not exist and `/mvc/public/adjoasdjaos` is not a directory and the `.htaccess` file is located inside the `/mvc/public` subdirectory (as you appear to have stated). Although that is different to the requirements stated in your question, it would seem to be more "useful". But that presumably does not happen?

Comment: Have you restarted apache?

Comment: For what it's worth, `public` is a common naming convention to imply that the contents of that folder are the only ones publicly exposed through the web server.